# Recursion using STL?

Tags: c++, recursion, stl

I wrote this function to trace a certain spot in a topological tree. However for some reason. Its infinite.

```
int electricity(int x){
    multimap<int,entita,greater<int> >::reverse_iterator it = siet.rbegin();
    advance(it,x-1);
    if((*it).second.z=='E') return (*it).second.i;
    return electricity((*it).first);
}
```

I debugged the variables in runtime and I am 100% certain that X is different from (*it).first. Yet for some reason, with every next function call the x remains the same. In this case (4). Any idea why?

Comment: Just as a side note: You can dereference the iterator like a pointer: e.g. `it->second.z` is the same as `(*it).second.z`. (This gets a bit tricky when the iterator dereferences to a pointer type but this is not the case here)

Comment: How many keys are in your map? Could it be that `advance` alters `it` to be the `siet.rend()` iterator?

Comment: I knew that :) but i learned it half way through. And somehow this became my preference.

Comment: There are 4 keys (in this case) and x-1 equals 3.

Comment: With those low numbers given: Could you please name all the keys you have and give a trace of the call stack of electricity until x starts to repeat on each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get an infinite recursion when the multimap contains an item that "refers" to itself or another item that directly or indirectly "refers" back to it.

To break the infinite recursion you have a couple of options:

- make sure that there are no cycles (if there are ant if possible, fix them) and then call this function
- or keep track of cycles inside this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion can be infinite in this case:

```
int electricity(int x){ // You call with some X
   multimap<int,entita,greater<int> >::reverse_iterator it = siet.rbegin();
   advance(it,x-1); // Now *it at some element, lets call it Z
   if((*it).second.z=='E') // False for Z
      return (*it).second.i;
   return electricity((*it).first); // Call himself with same X, e.g. X == it->first
}
```

So, reason to be infinite is: this algorithm is wrong; or getting unexpected data in `siet`